# Casting from base Model instance to derived proxy Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'd like to define a proxy Model for Django's default User class, something kind of like this:

```
class MyUser(User):

    def pretty_username(self): 
        if self.first_name:
            return self.first_name
        return self.username 

    class Meta: 
        proxy = True
```

And, I'd like to be able to call pretty_username from view code (and ideally, even from templates).  Is there a simple way to take an instance of a standard User Model and type-cast it into an instance of MyUser?

Even some `__init__` magic would be okay with me, as long as I can say:

```
my_user = MyUser(request.user)
```

in my view code.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a wrapper or adapter for the User class. Would something like this: http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2009/03/27/the-adapter-pattern-in-python/

do the trick?

Answer (score 9):

I think the actual answer to this question should be the comment by @fhahn in the other answer.  And by changing **class** we can avoid the extra database call.  Here is sample code:

My proxy model which change the representation from `username` to `email` if set:

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = _('my user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('my users')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.email or self.username)

class Wallet(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='wallet')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.owner
```

A brief test in shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from my_apps.models import MyUser
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=4)
>>> user
<User: AbKec6rumI9H9UmAC3Bh2kXUHzj4>
>>> user.email
'john@example.com'
>>> user.wallet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'wallet'
>>> user.__class__ = MyUser
>>> user
<MyUser: john@example.com>
>>> user.wallet
<Wallet: john@example.com>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to have the full proxy object available, this is a quick and dirty solution (at the expense of an extra database call)

```
class MyUser(User):

    def pretty_username(self): 
        if self.first_name:
            return self.first_name
        return self.username 

    class Meta: 
        proxy = True


def get_myuser(self):
    try:
        return MyUser.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None

User.add_to_class('get_myuser', get_myuser)
```

So to use this in a view you could say:

```
request.user.get_myuser().pretty_username()
```

Or in a template:

```
{{ request.user.get_myuser.pretty_username }}
```

A nicer solution, if you're not tied to the proxy model idea, would be the following:

```
def pretty_username(self):
    if self.first_name:
        return self.first_name
    return self.username

User.add_to_class('pretty_username', pretty_username)
```

This would allow the following:

```
request.user.pretty_username()
```

Or

```
{{ request.user.pretty_username }}
```

Comment: The get_myuser method has to change the type of the user object from User to MyUser. This can be done using the `__class__` attribute: `def get_myuser(self): self.__class__ = MyUser` without an additional database call