# Django, how to cast base model to proxy model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a place in my code, where I need to overload model's property. For this matter I'm using proxy model of my base instance.

models:

```
class Question(TimeTrack):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        SINGLE_CHOICE = "SC", _("single_choice")
        MANY_CHOICE = "MC", _("many_choice")
        TRUE_FALSE = "TF", _("true_false")
        CHRONOLOGY = "CHR", _("chronology")
        MATCHING = "MCH", _("matching")

    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    image_src = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    feedback = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Types.choices)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()

    @property
    def correct_answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.filter(is_correct=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Question #{self.id}"

class ShuffledQuestion(Question):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    
    @property
    def answers(self):
        _answers = list(super().answers)
        random.shuffle(_answers)
        return _answers
```

and the place where I create proxy:

```
_question_data = model_to_dict(question)
_question_data["quiz"] = question.quiz
_question_data["group"] = question.group
newQuestion = ShuffledQuestion(**_question_data)
```

The above works just fine, but I wonder if there is "more elegant" way to accomplish the same.

Comment: Won't it work the same way if you do ShuufledQuestion.objects.get(pk=question.pk)?

Comment: Działa, dzięki Tomek :)

Comment: Posted comment as answer, If you think that my answer has been helpful feel free to  upvote it and/or mark it as accepted. No pressure, posted it for future readers because comments can dissapear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really cast model data into it's proxy model, because proxy model has same data as original model, they share same table in DB after all.

To "cast" model into it's proxy you can use `get` method on proxy model queryset:

```
ShuufledQuestion.objects.get(pk=question.pk)
```

And it will have same data as original model, but different Django methods/properties/managers etc.

Comment: But how do I do that for models that are already fetched, like `user` in `request.user`? I have an `Employee` proxy model over `User`, and want to cast `self.request.user` in a view to that `Employee`. `Employee(self.request.user)` doesn't do the trick ;-) - Bit I don't know how.

Comment: There is a bit of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919592/casting-from-base-model-instance-to-derived-proxy-model-in-django), in short: refetch the object again with the new model (+extra DB call), or dumb-hack the attributes to the new model using monkey patching. BÄH.